# Get /dev/ name of a specific USB device on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, usb

My question will be simple :

I need to get the /dev id of a specific USB device to use it in a Docker container.

But I've see few Linux commands that don't run on macOS.

Do you know an easy step to know that ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by */dev id*? Do you mean the device's file path within the */dev* directory? If so, are you interested in the path of the host (outside the container) or within the container? What kind of USB device is it (depending on the class of the device, they are handled differently and likely appear in multiple locations)?

Comment: @Codo, well, yes, I want to know the device file path in the /dev directory. In fact, it's a programable and open-source calculator (NumWorks (a French brand)) that I want to build in a Docker container)